# Cannot cast from android.app.Application to custom type

Tags: java, android, xml

I made a class that will hold application wide variables. I made it extend activity and even included it in the manifest but I'm still getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.blacksmith/com.example.blacksmith.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.blacksmith.GlobalVars
```

Here is the class:

```
package com.example.blacksmith;

import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVars extends Application {

    private Boolean DefaultEncrypt;
    private String Password;

    public GlobalVars(){
        DefaultEncrypt = true;
    }

    public void setDefaultEncrypt(Boolean is){
        DefaultEncrypt = is;
    }

    public Boolean getDefaultEncrypt(){
        return DefaultEncrypt;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass){
        Password = pass;
    }
    public String getPassword(){
        return Password;
    }

}
```

Here is the android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.blacksmith"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Blacksmith"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordCreatorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_password_creator" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>


    </application>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:name=".application.GlobalVars">

     </application>


</manifest>
```

This is how I'm accessing it:

```
GlobalVars tmp = ((GlobalVars) getApplicationContext());
tmp.setDefaultEncrypt(sharedPref.getBoolean("Default", true));
tmp.setPassword(sharedPref.getString("password", "0x1234"));
```

Note: I tried this.getApplication() and getApplication() and neither worked

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: your application must contain the running activity, so you need to remove the second application node from your manifest and set the name of the first application to `GlobalVars`

Comment: If you put this as an answer I'll give it a check

Comment: you can check nPn answer, its correct too

Comment: @MoshErsan, thanks, but if you comment was before my answer, feel free to add an answer and have the OP accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but you have 2 application stanzas,  try moving/replacing the items in :

```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:name=".application.GlobalVars">

     </application>
```

into your original application stanza :

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name=".application.GlobalVars" 
   >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Blacksmith"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PasswordCreatorActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_password_creator" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        </activity>


    </application>
```